# Is there a library or tool for zipping numerous files

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I've downloaded ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib and DotNetZip.  I'm zipping over 100 files at a time varying a meg to 4 megs.  When I use ICSharpCode I get a 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' error.  DotNetZip fails on the finalizing of the file every time.

Also, I'm working on sharepoint folders (mapped to my local drive)

```
private bool zipall()
//ICSharpCode
{
    int i = 0;
    progressBarzipping.Minimum = 0;
    progressBarzipping.Maximum = listBoxfiles.Items.Count;
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(textBoxDropPath.Text + "\\" + textBoxZipFileName.Text + ".zip"));
    foreach (string fName in listBoxfiles.Items)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fName);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fi.Name);
            FileStream sReader = File.OpenRead(fName);
            byte[] buff = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(sReader.Length)];
            sReader.Read(buff, 0, (int)sReader.Length);
            entry.DateTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
            entry.Size = sReader.Length;
            sReader.Close();
            zipOut.PutNextEntry(entry);
            zipOut.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zip Failed");
            zipOut.Finish();
            zipOut.Close();
            progressBarzipping.Value = 0;
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        progressBarzipping.Value = i;
    }
    zipOut.Finish();
    zipOut.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Zip Complete");
    progressBarzipping.Value = 0;
    return true;

}

//Not sure but I think this was my DotNetZip approach
//using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
//  {
//     foreach(string file in listboxFiles.Items)
//       {
//         zip.AddFile(file);
//       }      
//  zip.Save(PathToNewZip);
//  }
```

Comment: Show your code for DotNetZip and the exception, and I can help you. It works fine with 100,000 files or more, 10gb or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the exception.  When using DotNetZip, I guess the problem *might* be with the sharepoint mapped drive.  DotNetZip normally will save the zip as a temp file, then rename it. Maybe this isn't working because of sharepoint.  If that's the case, try opening a filestream and saving it to that stream.  This avoids the rename operation.

```
progressBarzipping.Minimum = 0; 
progressBarzipping.Maximum = listBoxfiles.Items.Count;
using (Stream fs = new FileStream(PathToNewZip, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()) 
    { 
       zip.AddFiles(listboxFiles.Items);

       // do the progress bar: 
       zip.SaveProgress += (sender, e) => {
          if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_BeforeWriteEntry) {
             progressBarzipping.PerformStep();
          }
       };

       zip.Save(fs); 
    }
}
```